rancher pull from insecure docker registry
I have 4 VM in local network:

1 - docker container - rancher
2 - rancher node
3 - rancher node
4 - docker container - registry

Linux mint 22, Rancher 2.10.1, cluster - v1.31.3+rke2r1 amd, calico.
I want to deploy app from server#4 private registry.
If I start docker registry without ssl sertificate, rancher writes "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client".
I tried to append insecure registry record to /etc/default/docker.json on server#1, no difference.
If I start docker registry with ssl sertificate, rancher writes "tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: sertificate signed by unknown authority".
Certificate:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj  "/CN=192.168.63.136" -addext "subjectAltName=IP:192.168.63.136" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.key -out domain.crt
and start docker registry with 
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key --volume=/data/certs:/certs

I added certificate to container and host-server#1.
I tried to add record to files
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/hosts.toml
/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/certs.d/192.168.63.136:5000/hosts.toml
I noticed that rancher rewrites file /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/certs.d/192.168.63.136:5000/hosts.toml after start with same content, bit without skip_verify = true:
server = "https://192.168.63.136"
[host."https://192.168.63.136"]
  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  skip_verify = true

If I set image value to http://ip:port/image_name, rancher writes that it's invalid format.
What I need to do to bypass tls verification? It's local network, I'm not able to get even letsencrypt certificate.

Solved:
cluster settings - registries - add mirror and auth with skip tls verify
